# S3 bucket resource not being found using data

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a `main.tf` that looks like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_notifications_bucket" {
  bucket        = local.s3_bucket_name
  force_destroy = true
}

module "s3_notification" {
  source              = "..."
  s3_bucket_name      = local.s3_bucket_name
  function_name       = module.lambda.lambda_function_name
  lambda_function_arn = module.lambda.lambda_arn
}
```

Module `s3_notification` uses a reference for that bucket. The reason for that is because when I am running locally, I will be creating this bucket. If it's deployed code, the bucket will already exist and I don't have to create it.

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_notifications_bucket" {
  bucket = var.s3_bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "aws_lambda_trigger" {
  bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.s3_notifications_bucket.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = var.lambda_function_arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
}
    
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = var.function_name
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${data.aws_s3_bucket.s3_notifications_bucket.id}"
}
```

However, when I run terraform apply, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed getting S3 bucket (my-bucket): NotFound: Not Found
... in data "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_notifications_bucket":
```

How do I make that bucket to be created before `data` reference gets processed?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need the data source in the notification module? Furthermore, can you which parameters are you passing to the module?

Comment: @MarkoE so the bucket already exists but I want to be able to test everything locally using LocalStack. Locally, I have to create that bucket. In PROD, bucket already exists so I just need a reference for it. The module is basically creating a lambda function and configuring S3 notifications.

Comment: Understood, but are there any arguments you are passing to the module when calling it?

Comment: @MarkoE indeed :) I updated with the variables.

Comment: Maybe I need `depends_on` in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no need to rely on using a data source in this case, there needs to be one slight change:

```
module "s3_notification" {
  source              = "..."
  s3_bucket_name      = aws_s3_bucket.s3_notifications_bucket.id
  function_name       = module.lambda.lambda_function_name
  lambda_function_arn = module.lambda.lambda_arn
}
```

This uses an implicit resource reference, which means that the S3 bucket will be created first, and only then the bucket name attribute will be passed to the `s3_bucket_name` in the module call.

Additionally, one change needs to happen in the module code as well:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "aws_lambda_trigger" {
  bucket = var.s3_bucket_name
  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = var.lambda_function_arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
}
```

and the data source can be dropped for local testing.

Comment: exactly what I needed! Using `depends_on` also did the trick but not a good practice here. Thanks Marko!

Comment: Yeah, I usually try to stay away from `depends_on` unless absolutely needed. :)